# Ignore Icon\r in emacs ido-find-file

Tags: macos, emacs

I want to ignore the hidden OS X `Icon\r` file in `ido-find-file`:

```
$ python -c 'import os; print [x for x in os.listdir(".") if "Icon" in x]'
['Icon\r']
```

I've tried:

```
(add-to-list 'ido-ignore-files "Icon\\r") ; doesn't work
(add-to-list 'ido-ignore-files "Icon\r") ; doesn't work
```

Only thing I got to work is:

```
(add-to-list 'ido-ignore-files "Icon")
```

This works, but seems a bit.. brute-force.

Comment: Not entirely sure if this belongs here, or on SuperUser, but [this quotes the FAQ and says it belongs here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79659/can-we-please-have-a-ruling-about-emacs-questions-on-so) (although [this contradicts it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43198/emacs-questions-super-user-or-stack-overflow))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a look at

```
(ido-file-name-all-completions "~/Dropbox")
```

you'll see that it contains something like:

```
(... "Icon\n" ...)
```

Meaning that somewhere Emacs turns the \r into \n
Actually, even file-name-all-completions does the same, it seems to be embedded quite far in the Emacs C code.

Anyway, that means you have to

```
(add-to-list 'ido-ignore-files "Icon\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

I have this setting in my `.emacs` Which may help your cause

```
(setq completion-ignored-extensions
  '(".o" ".elc" "~" ".bin" ".bak" ".obj" ".map" ".a" ".ln" ".mod"))
```

UPDATE:
how about some thing like this?

```
 (setq ido-ignore-files '("Icon^R"))
```

Comment: Hm, that didn't work, sadly. The `^R` isn't a literal carat-and-R, it's the `\r` escape sequence